# Linq error while dragging and dropping my table from server explorer to dbml file

Tags: c#, linq

I am currently working with `LINQ` and I got the problem ! I don't know why it seems like that ! Yesterday it was working totally fine ! I have dragged one table from my server explorer and dropped into dbml file and suddenly i got this error box...

> one or more selected items contain a data type that is not supported
>   by the designer

Let me give you table definition:

[Table definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnsCD.png)

Comment: Do you want us to guess? Show the code please...

Comment: It doesn't give runtime error

Comment: I m trying to drag table and if i drop on dbml file ... then BOOM !! error popups !

Comment: well, what column types does it have?

Comment: There is no column type like nvarchar or nchar ! I use "Computed column specification n--> Formula" value ([Node].[GetLevel]()) and "Is Persisted" as "yes". It don't allow me to edit data type !

Comment: @NoOne: Try without the HierarchyId type, the rest including the computed column looks ok.

Answer (score 0):

The [Level] column is missing a datatype. If you didn't mean for that to be there, and it wasn't there when you tried it, then it's possible the hierarchyid.